# SQL ordering by text ASC, show numbers at last position

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I have a SQL query and I need to order the result in ASC, but I need the numbers and spaces to be in the last position of the result, not first.

```
SELECT title FROM movie ORDER BY title ASC
```

Using the code above I get the titles starting from [space], 0-9, A,B,C... I need this form: A,B,C,...,Z,[anything else]

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ORDER BY CASE
           WHEN LOWER(LEFT(title, 1)) BETWEEN 'a' AND 'z' THEN 0
           ELSE 1
         END,
         title
```

Comment: Only alteration I had it make is that `LEFT()` is not recognised by Sqlite, but worked wonderfully.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a hack, but it should work.

```
SELECT title FROM movie 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN title LIKE '[0-9]%' THEN 'ZZZ' + title ELSE title END ASC
```

The idea is to make your order clause transform the items starting with numbers by prepending them with ZZZ.  As for the items starting with a space, you may just want to clean them up with LTRIM.

Comment: I think zerkms' answer is better and recommend you go that route.  I'll leave this here in case anyone wants a cruder alternative :-)